# Detecting when a row has changed in a dataset/datatable

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, data-binding

I'm trying to add some extra logging to my C# winforms application. I have a few data bound forms that all the database stuff is managed by a binding source and some typed datasets/adapters.

With this setup, it's kind of difficult to tell when something is changed, I'd have to manage each field and keep it's previous value. Is there a way I can hook into the dataset and tell when something is changed? I know datarow's have a RowState enumeration, would that be a good place to start? I looked into the binding source's DataMemberChanged event but it never fired so...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use the [RowChanged](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.datatable.rowchanged.aspx) event, the [RowChanging](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.datatable.rowchanging.aspx) event, or any of the [other events](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.datatable_events.aspx) raised by a DataTable.

Comment: Will these also give me the previous value(s)? Or is that too much to ask?

Comment: I don't think it will.  I know that you can roll back the changes by calling RejectChanges to restore the row to its previous value.

Comment: Can I tell which column changed?

Comment: I could do a quick query to the database to grab the row and check it..., that might be expensive though. And may not be fool proof if the update query executes first.

Comment: @Malfist: The [ColumnChanging](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.datatable.columnchanging.aspx) event can be used to figure out which column is changing and what the proposed new value will be.

Answer (score 16):

To get the original value of an updated Data value you can do this:

```
<DataTableRow>[<DataColumn>, DataRowVersion.Original]
```

Comment: I wish I could split the credit for the right answer...Thank you!

Comment: That's great information.  THANK YOU!  I'll use that myself.  I wish I could vote you up more than once for that.

Answer (score 5):

To know what has changed look at the [DataSet.GetChanges method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/a4ey25we.aspx). The example shows how to get the changes and go through them. I also have an [old example here](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/forums/en-US/winformsdatacontrols/thread/d86e4302-70eb-409c-9ee9-e470e3da6e72/) that uses a DataTable and shows how to do a comparison after a merge. It inspects the RowState and shows the changed values etc. It's near the bottom of the page and it's in VB since the OP was using that, not C#. I'm headed out now so I can't provide an equivalent translation but it should be pretty straightforward to glean some useful techniques from.