# Comparing DataGridView's changed cell to the DGV's original value in that cell

Tags: c#, winforms, datagridview, datatable

In a C# WinForms project I'm trying to highlight a cell that the user changes a value in (change the BackColor) for later review to allow the user to adjust any changes they make and then finally to save those changed cells to the database on a button click.

I've been using the DGV's CellValueChanged event to call the function that will check for changes and highlight the changed cell. The `CellValueChanged` event is just this:

```
private void dgvCategories_CellValueChanged(object sender, DataGridViewCellEventArgs e)
{
    CompareDgvToDataTable(dtCategories, e.RowIndex, e.ColumnIndex);
}
```

`CompareDgvToDataTable()` looks like this at the moment:

```
private void CompareDgvToDataTable(DataTable dt, int intRowIndex, int intColumnIndex)
{
    if (dt.Rows[intRowIndex][intColumnIndex].ToString() != dgvCategories.Rows[intRowIndex].Cells[intColumnIndex].Value.ToString())
    {
        // Change the BackColor
    }
}
```

`dtCategories` is a variable available to the whole form and is (re)populated whenever the DGV gets rebuilt. As you can see I'm not really doing anything yet. I'm just trying to make sure I'm getting the correct cell and can properly compare the original and user-edited values for now.

However my comparison isn't behaving the way that I expected it to.

It was my assumption that the DGV's DataTable doesn't change until the DGV's datasource is reloaded, but that's apparently not the case. The above `if ()` check always evaluates to false (both sides of the comparison are the same value), as the DataTable's cell and the corresponding DGV cell are the same at that point.

How do I access the original value that the DGV was loaded with to compare that to what the user changes it to - including if the user changes the value back to the original DataTable's value?

Comment: Deal with the data source to monitor the data manipulation and make the DGV visualize that in a way or another. Check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1578097/detecting-when-a-row-has-changed-in-a-dataset-datatable/1578256) for example.

Comment: Is the DatagridView.DataSource set to the DataTable? It is hard to tell from usage in the code you have shown.

Comment: @JQSOFT, after some research I found that `DataRowVersion.Original` and `DataRowVersion.Proposed` were what I needed.

Comment: @TnTinMn, Yes it is, see my reply to JQSOFT. using `DataRowVersion` suits my purposes.